# How to Convert Xamarin ImageSource to a Format for Pixel Manipulation (e.g., SkiaSharp or GDI)?

Tags: c#, xamarin, gdi, skiasharp

I'm working on a Xamarin.Forms project where I need to perform pixel-level manipulation on images loaded through Xamarin's ImageSource. I'm looking for a way to convert the ImageSource to a format that allows me to set and get individual pixels for tasks such as drawing and pixel manipulation.

I've tried using SkiaSharp, and I've encountered issues with converting ImageSource to SKBitmap. Here's a snippet of my code:

```
// Example using SkiaSharp
ImageSource imageSource = // my ImageSource;
SKBitmap skBitmap = SKBitmap.Decode(imageSource.ToStream());
```

However, I'm facing challenges, and I'm open to exploring alternative libraries or methods that can achieve the same goal. My objective is to have the flexibility to set and get individual pixel values for image manipulation.

Additionally, if there's a way to achieve this using GDI in a Xamarin context, I'd be interested in exploring that avenue as well.

I appreciate any guidance or examples on how to effectively convert ImageSource to a format suitable for pixel manipulation, and if there are alternative libraries or approaches that I might consider.

Thank you!

Comment: You have repeatedly asked some variation of this question, but do not respond to the comments or suggestions that we are making.  I still don't understand why you are using an `ImageSource` to do this, as opposed to just using the original data used to create the `ImageSource`

Comment: I'm creating an image editor app which needs to combine multiple images into one. I did it easily in winforms and with gdi but here i decided to set my images to `ImageButton`s and make the click event of them for selecting and other commands. So from my app it can create an `ImageButton` in several ways for example from file or from url or from clipboard or camera or ... . And here no matter what method does the image button created i need to draw and edit the image of it to the main screen. I translate all of my 12000 lines of gdi code to skiasharp and it looks perfect but this one.

Comment: to get the original image data, for `StreamImageSource`, use `Stream`.  For `FileImageSource`, use `File`.  For `UriImageSource`, use `Uri`.

Comment: That's the point, I want to use them with a single operation. I don't want to check or set or i better say sort them to multiple groups. For example in gdi i can set a `PictureBox` image from a downloaded source with webclient or with `ImageLocation` and then use that image like other ways like from file and they're all with this: `pictureBox1.Image`.

Comment: I don't see a way to do that.  You're going to have to write some code to do it.

Comment: Besides, The user can load an image from url and then turn off the internet and with anychange and need for redrawing, The image couldn't load.

Answer (score 0):

For pixel-level manipulation of images in Xamarin.Forms, SkiaSharp is indeed a solid choice. To deal with `ImageSource`, we must convert it into a stream or a format that SkiaSharp can decode into an `SKBitmap`. The `ImageSource` class doesn't have a built-in method to directly convert it to a stream or a `SKBitmap`, but we can use different types of `ImageSource` (like `UriImageSource`, `FileImageSource`, etc.) to get the underlying image data.

Below is an example of converting a `StreamImageSource` to `SKBitmap`:

```cs
// Assuming your ImageSource is a StreamImageSource
var imageSource = // your StreamImageSource;

// Get the stream of the image source
StreamImageSource streamImageSource = (StreamImageSource)imageSource;
using (Stream stream = await streamImageSource.Stream(System.Threading.CancellationToken.None))
{
    // Decode the stream to SKBitmap using SkiaSharp
    SKBitmap skBitmap = SKBitmap.Decode(stream);

    // Now you can manipulate pixels with the SKBitmap
}
```

If you have a `FileImageSource`, you can directly read the file into an `SKBitmap`:

```cs
// Assuming your ImageSource is a FileImageSource
var imageSource = // your FileImageSource
FileImageSource fileImageSource = (FileImageSource)imageSource;
string filePath = fileImageSource.File;

// Decode the file to SKBitmap using SkiaSharp
SKBitmap skBitmap = SKBitmap.Decode(filePath);

// Now you can manipulate pixels with the SKBitmap
```

For `UriImageSource`, you would first download the image data into a `Stream`, then decode that `Stream` into an `SKBitmap`:

```cs
// Assuming your ImageSource is a UriImageSource
var imageSource = // your UriImageSource
UriImageSource uriImageSource = (UriImageSource)imageSource;

using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
using (Stream stream = await client.GetStreamAsync(uriImageSource.Uri))
{
    // Decode the stream to SKBitmap using SkiaSharp
    SKBitmap skBitmap = SKBitmap.Decode(stream);

    // Now you can manipulate pixels with the SKBitmap
}
```

Concerning GDI, it's important to note that GDI+ is not directly accessible in Xamarin.Forms as it's a .NET System.Drawing based library suited for Windows Forms and not for cross-platform code. Since Xamarin.Forms is cross-platform, it relies on different graphics APIs on each platform (like Core Graphics on iOS and Canvas on Android). Therefore, using SkiaSharp is a preferred method since it is cross-platform and has broad capabilities for graphics and image manipulation.

For actual pixel manipulation, once you have `SKBitmap`, you can access the `Pixels` property:

```cs
// Access pixel at (x, y)
SKColor color = skBitmap.GetPixel(x, y);

// Modify pixel at (x, y)
skBitmap.SetPixel(x, y, new SKColor(r, g, b, a)); // where r, g, b, a are byte values of red, green, blue, and alpha channels
```

Remember to handle exceptions and edge cases where the `ImageSource` might not contain valid image data or the image could not be decoded. Depending on where and how you're obtaining the images, you may also need to handle issues such as permissions, network failures, or incorrect file paths.